# Error when i visualize shiny app (after correct deployment)

Tags: r, shiny

i deployed a Shiny app "without problems" (i got "Application successfully deployed to..."), but when i want to visualize it, the url show me this:

> ERROR: string multibyte 2 inválida

[image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoZSr.png)

What do you think it is happens?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shinyapps-users/cpqDA2FqAao/rCsE66iByeUJ;context-place=forum/shinyapps-users)

It is related to 'fileEncoding' argument in read.csv() function.

> Please read the article http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html 
>   (in particular, the section "File Input/Output") It looks like you 
>   have to specify the fileEncoding argument of read.csv().
>
> Regards,  Yihui